# Where can I edit, API management, publisher portal statistic pages?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have setup an Api-management service in Azure and i can see the default statistics in the publisher portal.

I want to include in my statistics `5xx errors` and i can't find a recommendation about this anywhere.

Is there a setting i am missing out?

The `Status codes` section in Health page is not providing any more details either, just a mention `failed` wont do the trick.

The preferred output would be either a statistics graph or a ratio completed/failed requests, or even totals of all these data(`500,400,200 error codes etc`) in any form that is available in api-managment service.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't customize those views. But there are a few options:

1. Some data like what you need you can get from Metrics in Azure portal.
2. There is also an API to pull raw log data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/reports/listbyrequest.
3. You could enable Application Insights integration.
4. You could log your own data using log-to-eventhub policy.

Comment: Application insights provides the total of requests and failed request meaning sum of 401,sum of 403, sum of 404 and sum of 500 and details for them. Thank you @VitaliyKurokhtin

Comment: As a clarification, in it's builtin reporting APIM calls: <=301, 304, 307 as Successful, 401, 403, 429 as Unauthorized, 400, >=500 <=600 as Failed, rest as Other.